# How to hyperlink an image that you upload on your timeline to an external website on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I have a business Facebook page. I would like to upload images to my timeline post and hyperlink them to external website or webpage. So, when people click on the image, it will take them to a website or webpage outside of Facebook. I have looked high and low on the Internet for help with this, but nothing is very promising. One website talked about downloading Facebook Iframe app and others saying just go to the uploaded image and click on it. There it will give you option to enter an URL for the image, but I don't see anything like that. I don't know if there is a difference in Personal Facebook Page and Business Facebook Page or if they work the same for both.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I don't think that you can. Facebook lets you embed a link, or an image, but not both at once. I think the best you can do is make sure the image you want to use is featured prominently on the page you want to link to.

Comment: @AlE. you should submit this as an answer.